# Can't get rid of white spaces on sides of header

Tags: html, css, header, blogs

I've decided to create my own blog, and am trying to work on the layout for it. I just started on it and I'm having trouble with the header already. I want a header that stretches all the way across the screen with no white spaces on top or on the sides and am planning on making my blog responsive. I've tried setting the margin to 0 and can't seem to get anything to work. I've tried to search the answer on here but couldn't get anything to work. this is my html and css. Thanks for any help!

p.s. The reason I did the logo in such a weird way is because I'm going to have one word in a bold font and one word in a skinny font and that was the only way I could think of to do it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title>FatHead | Blog</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700,800|Muli:400,300italic,400itali" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

<head>

</head>

<body>
<div class="header">

    <div class="logo">

        <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1><h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="nav">

    </div>

</div>






</body>    


</html>`
```

CSS:

```
.header{
background-color: lightslategray;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;


}

.logo{
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin:15px;
}

#logo-large{
display: inline;
}

#logo-small{
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
body
 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
```

and change your css

```
.logo{
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
  margin:15px;
 }
```

to this

```
  .logo{
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
  margin:0 15px 15px 15px;
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f03ukjno/)

Comment: That sure did work! I can't believe I didn't think about the header only being able to go as wide as the body allows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the appropriate margins from `body` and `.logo`.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: lightslategray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 15px 15px;
}
#logo-large {
  display: inline;
}
#logo-small {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="logo">

    <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1>
    <h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="nav">

  </div>

</div>
```